# Rerunning __init__ method

Tags: python-3.x, class

Assuming you have a class defined as follows:

```
class Bar():
     def __init__(self):
          #do something on initialization
```

and then create a new object:

```
foo = Bar()
```

I understand that the creation of `foo` executes the `__init__` method in the class.

If, however, later I would like to re-run the `#do something else on initialization` code - how is that done?  My `foo` object has other attributes that are specific to the `foo` instance.

If the answer is create a new object, such as `foo2 = Bar()` a second time, then is there a way to preserve the original `foo` object attributes that were created and associate them with `foo2`?

Being new to Python, I'm trying not to rewrite the `__init__` code again in a second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just put your initialisation code in a method and call it from **init** as well as the other locations you need it called from?